# "plotting" and Matplotlib - Is 'plotting' missing from library and need its own install?

Tags: python

I imported matplotlib. Python 3.X, Mac OS, Chrome.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotting import plot_diagram, plot_landscapes
from plotting import plot_betti_surfaces, plot_betti_curves
```

---

I get this error. Anyone know why and how to fix? 
Is 'plotting' part of a different library, needing installation from some other package?
Thank you.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-8c06bd9c066e> in <module>
     11 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     12 from plotting import plot_diagram, plot_landscapes
---> 13 from plotting import plot_betti_surfaces, plot_betti_curves
     14 from plotting import plot_point_cloud
     15 from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters

ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_betti_surfaces' from 'plotting' (/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotting/__init__.py)

----------


 ##
```

Comment: If you copied the import statements from somewhere, can you share the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `plot_betti_surfaces` is part of a different package, "giotto-tda".

https://docs-tda.giotto.ai/latest/modules/generated/plotting/gtda.plotting.plot_betti_surfaces.html

Comment: Could be. How did you figure that out? I will check giotto-tda....Thanks.

Comment: Amazing. How did you figure that out?

Comment: I copied the name into a Google search :-)  If this helps, can you accept my answer?

Comment: Thank you.  I copied the source code from the original author of the code, copied/pasted, and it worked. Don't ask me why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed installing [plotting](https://pypi.org/project/plotting/).

```
pip install plotting
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I think I did try. Another suggested 'plotting' is part of 'giotto-tda' so I will try to figure that out.

Comment: Yes, try installing pip install -U giotto-tda